# PHP pred_split Regex expression to return html tags within a sub-string

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I have read many threads on this regex question, but none of them seem to work.  I am sure it's a result of me really not understanding regex expressions.

Let's say I have the following string:

```
string='<i>he<a herf="http://www.cnn.com">ll</b>o</i>'
```

I would like to grab the html tags buried in the substring "hello".  I am using the following php function:

```
$temp = preg_split('/[0-9A-Za-z]+</', $string);
```

What I am looking for is an array with the following:

```
a herf="http://www.cnn.com">, and /b>
```

I can tack on the leading '<'.  My results, using the above regex in my preg_split call seem to be including the first '' tag

My full code:

```
$string = '<i>he<a herf="http://www.cnn.com">ll</b>o</i>';
$temp = preg_split('/[0-9A-Za-z]+</', $string);
echo('<pre>');print_r($temp);echo('</pre>');
$num = count($temp);
$counter = 1;
foreach($temp as $key=>$tag_stem){
    if($counter<$num) {
        echo('<xmp>');print_r('tag_stem = ' . $tag_stem);echo('</xmp>');
        $temp_tag = '<' . $tag_stem;

        echo('<xmp>');print_r('temp tag = ' . $temp_tag);echo('</xmp>');
    if (empty($temp2)) {
        $temp2 = str_replace($temp_tag, '', $string);
    } else {
        $temp2 = str_replace($temp_tag, '', $temp2);
    }
    echo('<xmp>');print_r('string = ' . $temp2);echo('</xmp>');

    if (strstr($temp_tag, '</')) {
        $temp2 = $temp2 . $temp_tag;
    } else {
        $temp2 = $temp_tag . $temp2;
    }
    echo('<xmp>');print_r("new string = " . $temp2);echo('</xmp>');
}
$counter++;
}
$temp_array = explode($word, $string);
echo('<xmp>');print_r("final string = " . $temp2);echo('</xmp>');
```

My results are as follows:

```
tag_stem = <i>
temp tag = <<i>

string = <i>he<a herf="http://www.cnn.com">ll</b>o</i>

new string = <<i><i>he<a herf="http://www.cnn.com">ll</b>o</i>

tag_stem = a herf="http://www.cnn.com">

temp tag = <a herf="http://www.cnn.com">

string = <<i><i>hell</b>o</i>

new string = <a herf="http://www.cnn.com"><<i><i>hell</b>o</i>

tag_stem = /b>

temp tag = </b>

string = <a herf="http://www.cnn.com"><<i><i>hello</i>

new string = <a herf="http://www.cnn.com"><<i><i>hello</i></b>

final string = <a herf="http://www.cnn.com"><<i><i>hello</i></b>
```

Not the first iteration.  For whatever reason, it's picking up the first `"<i>".`

Comment: 1) Regular expressions and markup don't mix. Regex is not equipped to process HTML/XML. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)  2) Your given string is a prime example of tag soup, which is arguably invalid markup to begin with. 3) PHP has got a DOM parser built-in (`DOMDocument`). Why mess about with regex if you can just parse the markup?

Comment: My overall application is taking the results of an html markup editor (nicEdit) and moving the tags embedded within a given word to either the front or the back of the word. It's ugly - I know.  This is why the html in my example is messy.  This is also why I am attempting to use regex to parse my string.  If there is a better way, I am open to it.

Comment: Well, I've mentioned a better way: [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/DOMDocument)